# Under what circumstances could Expires, Last-Modified and ETags headers be ignored?

Tags: caching, http-headers, etag, last-modified

I have a web site that is recieving many unexpected requests for static resources (images, css files etc) that I would expect to be being served straight from the browser's cache.  This is a performance problem and I can't understand why it is happening.

For each static resource the web site returns an `Expires` header of 24 hours in the future, a `Last-Modified` header of the date of modification of the image/css file and an `ETag`:

```
Expires: Wed, 07 Dec 2011 13:50:47 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 14 Jul 2011 15:19:16 GMT
ETag: W/"4875-1310656756000"
```

With these settings I'd expect that, after the first time the browser requests an image or css file:

- it would not re-request the resource for another 24 hours
- after 24 hours it would re-request the resource, passing an `If-Modified-Since` header and an `If-None-Match` header, to which the server would respond with a `304` status (assuming nothing has changed server-side).

This is what happens most of the time.

*However I see some browser sessions where the static resources don't appear to be cached and are requested for every page*.

Looking at these requests I don't see any `If-Modified-Since` or `If-None-Match` headers being received.  The server is then responding with a `200` status each time, and returning the requested resource.  This is a performance problem that I want to track down.

I suspect that the problem is due to the presence of an HTTP proxy/cache between browser and web site (problem sessions usually come from behind corporate firewalls).  If so, I don't understand why a Proxy would be interferring with the `Expires`/`Etag`/`Last-Modified` headers in this way.

A couple of pieces of additional info in case they are relevant:

- I don't currently set a `Date` header.  Is that needed for the `Expires` / `Last-Modified` headers to work correctly?
- I don't currently set a `Cache-Control` header, having thought that `Expires` / `Last-Modified` would be "good enough".
- The web site is deployed over both https and http, and I've seen the issue in both deployments.  I'd thought that this would stop a proxy being the cause, but now understand that some proxies do intercept SSL traffic.

Has anyone else experienced anything similar and found out why it happens?

Comment: Remember, these mechanisms *allow* a browser to cache responses, but the browser is not *required* to perform any caching at all.

Comment: Are the offending requests GET or HEAD requests?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I understand that I can't *force* the browser to cache these responses.  I'm trying to understand what settings / policies might be in place in the browser or proxy that could cause what I'm seeing.  I have customers that experience the poor performance and would like to know how to improve it.

Comment: Have you looked at the IP / useragent of these requests